# Visual Studio / Silverlight debug opens file directory

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to debug a silverlight application but every time I try too it just opens up the file directory the project is in, it won't even work if I attach it to the process that has been loaded up already.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need more information to diagnose the problem. An error/exception, something...

Comment: I found the solution Chris, if you click on Index.html when it opens up the directory it will run it in the debugger - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, in IIS Directory Browsing was enabled - you can click on the file within the directory that loads up to continue onto debugging it.